# Border-image с одной стороны блока

Tags: css, css3

Есть ли возможность задать `border-image` только с одной стороны блока (не вокруг)? Например, если необходимо сделать тот же `border-bottom: dotted`, только с промежутком между точками и с размером точек на свое усмотрение.

Answer (score 1):

```
border-image-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
```

- Первый параметр - ширина сверху.
- Второй параметр - ширина справа.
- Третий параметр - ширина слева.
- Четвертый параметр - ширина снизу.

Можно использовать три параметра, тогда средний параметр определяет ширину обеих боковых границ.

Answer (score 0):

`border: solid transparent; border-width: 0 0 3px; border-image:...` для отображения только снизу, к примеру. Или как указал Эникейщик.